# Scala/Spark/Databricks: How to import code from user-created JAR?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, databricks

I have a JAR that I created with intellij and sbt, that defines a case class and Object. I've uploaded it to my databricks workspace, and attached it to a cluster as a library.

How do I actually import code from it/reference it in my notebook? So far all I can think of is to try

```
import NameOfJar._
```

which gives

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DataFrameComparison$
```

Do I need to have built the jar differently somehow? (Package statement or something?)

Answer (score 2):

you should import `import packageName._`, jar name is not used in import statement. It should work the same as in usual local java/scala code.

You can check this article for details - https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html

Btw, does your notebook fail on import itself, or later, when you're trying to use class, that exists inside jar?

Comment: So, originally I didn't have a package statement in the source file. (I'm probably making a lot of dumb mistakes, I'm not at all used to working with build systems)

Now it's doing something odd - it imports, but I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when I try to call methods. It clearly sees the class though (I can import `packageName.className` but not `packageName.mispelledClassName`)